# How can I write a RESTful controller that requires one of N parent resources to exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, cancan

We use CanCan. In our library application, a `Book` or `Magazine` can be checked out:

```
POST /books/123/loans      # LoansController#new :book_id     => 123
POST /magazines/456/loans  # LoansController#new :magazine_id => 456
```

`Books` and `Magazines` have a parent class `Stockable`, so the above is equivalent to:

```
POST /stockables/123/loans  # LoansController#new :stockable_id => 123
POST /stockables/456/loans  # LoansController#new :stockable_id => 456
```

However, not every `Stockable` can be loaned:

```
# error: can't check out reference books from the library
POST /reference_books/789/loans # LoansController#new :reference_book_id => 789

# same error
POST /stockables/789/loans      # LoansController#new :stockable_id      => 789
```

What's the right way to write the `LoansController` with CanCan so that it can handle anything that's `Loanable`, without needing to make a specific route for everything that's `Loanable`?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `ability.rb` to define what actions are / are not allowed for each object type. The following is assuming you're using STI, and so there is a `stockable_type` column containing the name of the class each row represents in your db. If you aren't using STI you can still use another method to correctly determine object type (probably by passing a block to the `can` and `cannot` methods instead of using the hash syntax [check the CanCan wiki, [Defining Abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities) for more info]).

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can [:read], :all
    can :new, Loan, :stockable_type => ["Book", "Magazine"]
    cannot :new, Loan, :stockable_type => "ReferenceBook"
  end
end
```

Then, just catch `CanCan::AccessDenied` in your `LoansController` and you can redirect people attempting to checkout reference books.

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  redirect_to some_url, :alert => "You can't check out reference books!"
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I like this solution, because it still exposes a route that is automatically broken (`POST /reference_books/123/loans`), which is not very RESTful.

Comment: If your routes.rb exposes `/reference_books/:id/loans`, isn't the fact that it's exposed irrelevant to what your question actually asked? There is no way to write your `LoansController` so that it doesn't expose a broken route - they're completely separate subsystems (as I'm sure you're aware).